# Android startactivityforresult not called after permissionrequest

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, runtime-permissions

OnActivityResult is not called and I wonder if it's because I just added a permissionrequest (it was working fine before). Below is the code, it's launching an intent with startactivityforresult after having requested a permission.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.v("showEmails","build<");
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "permission_rationale", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        Log.v("showEmails","requestPermissions");
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        ImageView ivShare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivShare);
        ivShare.setImageURI(imageUri);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("application/image");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textIntent);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        emailIntent.setFlags(0);
        startActivityForResult(emailIntent, GMAILSENT);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug  what error or exception u getting?

Comment: what is targetSdkVersion in your app gradle . please be sure that it is targeting marshmallow or higher.

Comment: I don't get any error... I put a Log.v after the startActivityForResult and I can see it in the console. 
targetSdkVersion = 23

Comment: 1. I guess you miss `emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailaddress);` and 2. maybe you should try `startActivity()` instead of `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: But if I use startActivity(), then it won't call onActivityResult that launches another method?

Comment: I've been over 30 solutions I found on stackoverflow but none of them worked. Any idea? Could it be because I'm calling startactivityforresult from  onrequestpermissionresult?